# Azure - Specifying Load Balancer Rules in ARM Template

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to modify an ARM template that I have which deploys some VMs and defines some autoscale rules (you can see the full template at https://gist.github.com/jinky32/d80e0ab2137236ff262484193f93c946, it is based on the template at https://github.com/gbowerman/azure-myriad/tree/master/vmss-ubuntu-scale).

I am trying to add in some load balancer rules so that traffic is spread across the new VMs as they are generated in reponse to the autoscale rules that are defined.

When I run this template via Azure CLI I get no errors in terminal but the deployment fails.  Digging into the error events I see two:

`statusCode:BadRequest serviceRequestId:ef42ec66-600e-4fb9-b4e2-dc2c06dda79c statusMessage:{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestFormat","message":"Cannot parse the request.","details":[{"code":"InvalidJsonReferenceFormat","message":"Reference Id cc2bepool is not formatted correctly. The Id is expected to reference resources of type loadBalancers/backendAddressPools. Path properties.loadBalancingRules[0].properties.backendAddressPool."}]}} responseBody:{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestFormat","message":"Cannot parse the request.","details":[{"code":"InvalidJsonReferenceFormat","message":"Reference Id cc2bepool is not formatted correctly. The Id is expected to reference resources of type loadBalancers/backendAddressPools. Path properties.loadBalancingRules[0].properties.backendAddressPool."}]}}`

and

`statusCode:BadRequest statusMessage:{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestFormat","message":"Cannot parse the request.","details":[{"code":"InvalidJsonReferenceFormat","message":"Reference Id cc2bepool is not formatted correctly. The Id is expected to reference resources of type loadBalancers/backendAddressPools. Path properties.loadBalancingRules[0].properties.backendAddressPool."}]}}`

I've put some of the relevant variables below and have also included my loadbalancer object but I believe that the issue is related to how I am referencing backendAddressPool:

```
"loadBalancingRules": [
      {
        "name": "LBRule",
        "properties": {
          "frontendIPConfiguration": {
            "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
          },
          "backendAddressPool": {
            "id": "[variables('bePoolName')]" 
          },
```

but I'm confused because I refer to it the same way elsewhere. Any advice on how to do this correctly much appreciated.

```
"variables": {
....
"loadBalancerName": "[concat(parameters('vmssName'), 'lb')]",
"lbProbeID": "[concat(variables('lbID'),'/probes/tcpProbe')]",
"publicIPAddressID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
"lbID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers',variables('loadBalancerName'))]",
"natPoolName": "[concat(parameters('vmssName'), 'natpool')]",
"bePoolName": "[concat(parameters('vmssName'), 'bepool')]",
....
....
}
.....
.....
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
  "name": "[variables('loadBalancerName')]",
  "location": "[variables('location')]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "frontendIPConfigurations": [
      ....
    ],
    "backendAddressPools": [
      {
        "name": "[variables('bePoolName')]"
      }
    ],
    "inboundNatPools": [
      {
        "name": "[variables('natPoolName')]",
        ...
      },
       {
        "name": "natpooltileserver",
        ....
      },
      {
        "name": "natpool2",
        ....
    ],
            "loadBalancingRules": [
      {
        "name": "LBRule",
        "properties": {
          "frontendIPConfiguration": {
            "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
          },
          "backendAddressPool": {
            "id": "[variables('bePoolName')]" 
          },
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "frontendPort": 80,
          "backendPort": 80,
          "enableFloatingIP": false,
          "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
          "probe": {
            "id": "[variables('lbProbeID')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "probes": [
      {
        "name": "tcpProbe",
        "properties": {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "port": 80,
          "intervalInSeconds": 5,
          "numberOfProbes": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

please go to the portal and open a support request to see what's wrong with your template edits.